# Cannot connect pptp vpn: Vpn service stopped

Tags: networking, vpn

I'm trying to connect to a pptp vpn. but I keep getting the error "vpn  service stopped" It used to work at beginning but then stopped working, and I don't know what exactly caused it to fail.

I tried playing with the all the configuration options but none of them made it work. I also tried making a manual connection through terminal using the guides which are avaialbe on internet but those didn't work either.

I can connect to my vpn via my android phone and windows laptop with no problem.